# Outer apply in kusto/ Azure AppInsights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am new to azure appinsight and kusto, I am trying to write a kusto query that will group items in a table and look for the latest record by time.

This is what i tried so far,

Sample Table:

```
let Temptable=datatable(RunId:string,Module:string,AppName:string,timestamp:datetime) [
  "1", "start",   "App1", '2020-02-27T04:30:01.6062658Z',
  "1", "end",   "App1", '2020-02-27T04:31:01.6062658Z',
  "2", "start",   "App1", '2020-02-27T04:00:01.6062658Z',
  "2", "end",   "App1", '2020-02-27T04:01:01.6062658Z',
  "3", "start",   "App1", '2020-02-27T03:30:01.6062658Z',
  "3", "end",   "App1", '2020-02-27T03:31:01.6062658Z',
  "4", "start",   "App1", '2020-02-27T03:00:01.6062658Z',
  "4", "end",   "App1", '2020-02-27T03:01:01.6062658Z',
  "5", "start",   "App1", '2020-02-27T02:30:01.6062658Z',
  "5", "end",   "App1", '2020-02-27T02:31:01.6062658Z',
  "6", "start",   "App2", '2020-02-27T04:00:01.6062658Z',
  "6", "end",   "App2", '2020-02-27T04:01:01.6062658Z',
  "7", "start",   "App2", '2020-02-27T03:00:01.6062658Z',
  "7", "end",   "App2", '2020-02-27T03:01:01.6062658Z',
  "8", "start",   "App2", '2020-02-27T02:00:01.6062658Z',
  "8", "end",   "App2", '2020-02-27T02:01:01.6062658Z',
  "9", "start",   "App2", '2020-02-27T01:00:01.6062658Z',
  "9", "end",   "App2", '2020-02-27T01:01:01.6062658Z',
  "10", "start",   "App2", '2020-02-27T00:30:01.6062658Z',
  "10", "end",   "App2", '2020-02-27T00:32:01.6062658Z'
];
```

I am running the below query,

```
let FactTable = Temptable
| where Module == "start"
| summarize by AppName
| project AppName;
FactTable
| lookup kind = inner (Temptable | partition by AppName( summarize Maxtime = max(timestamp) by AppName | top 1 by Maxtime desc nulls last )) on AppName;
```

My output:

[image]

I need to retrieve all the columns for the latest record.

Below is the query in sql, which will retrieve top 1 record for the particular AppName.

```
select cs.* 
    from (select AppName from #TempTable where Module = 'start' group by AppName) a
    outer apply (select top 1 * from #TempTable b where b.AppName = a.AppName order by [TimeStamp] desc) cs
```

[image]

How to achieve this in Kusto Query.

Is there anyway to write query in kusto with outer column can be accessible in the subquery,or any other better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for [arg_max()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction) aggregation function:

For example:

```
Temptable
| summarize arg_max(timestamp,*) by AppName
```